# share image+text in LinkedIn android

Tags: android, android-intent, linkedin-api

How to post image+text in LinkedIn from my application in android.

I have tried too many solutions but didn't find a proper way or any example to share image and text both at the same time on LinkedIn.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to share both image and text on LinkedIn.  You may pick one option:

- Share image.
- Share description.

If you try to share both, you will only see an image.

*[Two weeks spent fighting with LinkedIn support confirmed this.](https://www.revoltlib.com/linkedin-social-share-url-broken-ticket.html)*  I tested this theory out on Wikipedia (has a description, no image) and GitHub (has both description and image).  Results?

[image]
[image]

**Wikipedia:** [Description ONLY -- Works (but no image)!](https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikipedia.org%2F)
**GitHub:** [Image ONLY -- Works (but no description)!](https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.github.com%2F)

I made [test site, with only description,](https://www.revoltlib.com/linkedin-social-share-url-test.html) to verify this, and it appears confirmed.
I'm well aware that the [Official Microsoft LinkedIn Share Documentation](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en) makes no mention whatsoever of this, but all direct experience seems to point in the other direction.